# Uneven borders of ellipse annotation when I try to rotate the PDF

Tags: itext

[image: ellipse not properly drawn]

I am trying to draw ellipse on a rotated PDF but the border of the ellipse appears thick and thin in center

Sample Code:

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createSquareCircle(stamper.getWriter(), rect, null, false);
annotation.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
annotation.setColor(getColor(annot.getBorderColor()));
// annotation.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(2, 2, 2));
// annotation.setColor(getColor(annot.getBorderColor()));
annotation.setBorderStyle(new PdfBorderDictionary(3.5f, PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_SOLID));
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(page);
if ((int) (orientation % 360) == 90 || (int) (orientation % 360) == 270)
{
    w = rect.getHeight();
    h = rect.getWidth();
}
else
{
    w = rect.getWidth();
    h = rect.getHeight();
}
PdfAppearance app = cb.createAppearance(w + 3.5f, h + 3.5f);
app.setColorStroke(getColor(annot.getBorderColor()));
app.setLineWidth(3.5);
app.ellipse(rect.getLeft() + 1.5, rect.getBottom() + 1.5, rect.getRight() - 1.5, rect.getTop() - 1.5);
app.stroke();
annotation.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, app);
stamper.addAnnotation(annotation, page);
```

Comment: Does the same happen without rotation, too?

Comment: @mkl, No , this happened for only 90 and 270 degree rotation

Comment: Have you already tried without that `if {...} else {...}`, simply using unrotated rectangle width and height?

Comment: In your other question you needed to switch the dimensions because there you set the rotation of the annotation. Here you don't explicitly rotate the annotation, thus no need to switch width and height.

Comment: @mkl, I have also tried without switching the width and height but border on the edges goes thin and thick.

Comment: *"I have also tried without switching the width and height but border on the edges goes thin and thick."* - Please share a sample PDF with that ellipse created without switching width and height.

Comment: @mkl, Please Find shared sample pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B42NqA5UnXMVTmozRG9TbWxsajQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hhmmm, it looks like a feature of iText (for rotated pages it attempts to pretend to the user that he has an upright coordinate system, not a rotated one) gets into your way. I will try and experiment later this week.

Comment: Just to make sure: What is the value of `orientation`? Is it the **Rotate** entry of the page? Or is it something different?

Comment: orientation is rotation angle of pdf  which we would like apply on pdf for rotate

Comment: *Which you **would like to apply***, so it's **not** the page rotation value which in the file **already is applied**. Ok, then i do have an idea. I don't know, though, whether I can create a proper answer before next week.

Comment: i will share me sample code so that you can have better clarity for my scenario : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B42NqA5UnXMVdGtWN29Hdjk1S1U

Comment: Great! I'll look at it later. But the reason why I won't be able to look into this in detail is that I'll hardly be at a computer, only smart phone, for the next days...

Answer (score 0):

As already assumed in a comment *a feature of iText (for rotated pages it attempts to pretend to the user that he has an upright coordinate system, not a rotated one) gets into your way.* This feature unfortunately does only affect the dimensions of the annotation itself, not of the appearances you create for it.

If a page has a 90° or 270° rotation, therefore, you have to use appearance dimensions whose width and height are switched compared to the annotation dimensions you used.

Furthermore, one also has to consider the switched dimensions when drawing the ellipse on the appearance template. The code in the question and in the example code shared via google drive forgot this.

Finally, one shall not override the switched dimensions of the appearance template using `PdfAppearance.setBoundingBox`. The code in the example code shared via google drive did this.

#### False Example

If I create an ellipse annotation with appearance on a rotated page like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(202 + 6f, 300, 200 + 100, 300 + 150);

PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createSquareCircle(stamper.getWriter(), rect, null, false);
annotation.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
annotation.setColor(BaseColor.RED);
annotation.setBorderStyle(new PdfBorderDictionary(3.5f, PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_SOLID));

PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(1);
PdfAppearance app = cb.createAppearance(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
app.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
app.setLineWidth(3.5);
app.ellipse( 1.5,  1.5, rect.getWidth() - 1.5, rect.getHeight() - 1.5);
app.stroke();
annotation.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, app);

stamper.addAnnotation(annotation, 1);
```

*([CreateEllipse](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/annotate/CreateEllipse.java#L169) test `testCreateEllipseAppearanceOnRotated`)*

I indeed get a funny ellipse:

[image: deformed ellipse]

#### Correct Example

If I create an ellipse annotation with appearance on a rotated page with switched dimensions like this, though:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(202 + 6f, 300, 200 + 100, 300 + 150);

PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createSquareCircle(stamper.getWriter(), rect, null, false);
annotation.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
annotation.setColor(BaseColor.RED);
annotation.setBorderStyle(new PdfBorderDictionary(3.5f, PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_SOLID));

PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(1);
// switched appearance dimensions
PdfAppearance app = cb.createAppearance(rect.getHeight(), rect.getWidth());
app.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
app.setLineWidth(3.5);
// draw ellipse using switched appearance dimensions
app.ellipse( 1.5,  1.5, rect.getHeight() - 1.5, rect.getWidth() - 1.5);
app.stroke();
annotation.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, app);

stamper.addAnnotation(annotation, 1);
```

*([CreateEllipse](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/annotate/CreateEllipse.java#L215) test `testCreateCorrectEllipseAppearanceOnRotated`)*

I get the expected ellipse:

[image: regular ellipse]